# Time Machine couldn't complete the backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

This is the 2nd time I got this error message:

[image]

On my Mac Pro, I use two HDs for Time Machine backup. Time Machine would use them alternatively. The other HD works fine. With this HD, I used Disk Utility to perform "First Aid" and no problem was found. However, the Time Machine still cannot back up to this HD.

On the previous error, I had to reformat the HD. Any suggestions on what I should do this time?

Comment: Are the disks formatted the same way on both?

Comment: The one that failed is formatted as Mac OS Extended. The other one is Mac OS Extended (Journalized).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that App Cleaner is the root cause of the problem. I used App Cleaner for quite some time and have purchased the premium version. My problem with App Cleaner started with its V6.0 version and I was still on High Sierra. So it was not a Mac OS problem.

Comment: did uninstalling the app correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8561149
 I tried just now and works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.